# Table relations in Base with ODBC connected SQlite ZeitgeistDB (Base tells not supported)

Tags: linux, libreoffice, odbc

There aren't too many programs, that provide access to the ZeitgeistDB in Linux. Tracker-Needle in Debian isn't even available, anymore. So i thought i might use LibreOffice Base to access the DB and create my own queries and formulars.

But to make that work, i first need to set relations. I would figure them out, but Base tells me that they aren't supported.

I frequently use ODBC connections and remember seeing some sort of options like enabling a foreign key. Actually that should be everything needed to set relations. But it won't work. I already tried to find all possible options, but couldn't find anything.

Is there any way to make that work?

```
[ZeitgeistDB]
Description=Zeitgeist
Driver=SQLite3
Database=/home/user/.data/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite
Timeout=100000
StepAPI=No
ShortNames=No
FKSupport=Yes
SyncPragma=NORMAL
JournalMode=DELETE
BigInt=No
LoadExt=
```

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to Linux/Unix itself

Comment: It IS about Linux ODBC, in case you missed that.